# Using Compare-Net-Objects to deep compare PSCustomObjects

Tags: json, powershell, compare, compare-net-objects

Can someone provide an example of how to use **Compare-Net-Objects** library to compare PSCustomObjects (in my case they are objects created by **Invoke-RestMethod** from JSON feeds) with all nested properties?

I tried:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("KellermanSoftware.Compare-NET-Objects.dll")
$feed1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://URL_To_JSON_Feed1
$feed2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://URL_To_JSON_Feed2
$feeds = [KellermanSoftware.CompareNetObjects.CompareLogic]::new()
$result = $feeds.Compare($feed1,$feed2)
```

But it does not compare and throws an error:

**Exception calling "Compare" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot compare objects with a non integer indexer for object .Members"**

Library: https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects

Comment: I suspect Compare-NET-Objects will work horribly on *any* custom PSObject, since it'll attempt to unravel the underlying object and not just the immediate properties of the object. You're probably better off trying to write your own comparer. How deeply nested are the values in the JSON?

Comment: Mathias, my JSONs have up to 10 levels in depth.